# File::exists() in Laravel 4.x not working when the project is served

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm developing a project in **Laravel 4.x**. I'm currently using `File::exists()` function on the `routes.php` as an error trap, the code looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
  if(File::exists("settings/config.xml") {
    // do something with the config.
    // then go to the site.
  }
  else {
    // cannot proceed anymore.
  }
});
```

**I'm developing my project on a WAMP Server**. Everything is fine and it returns true *until I served it* `(php artisan serve --port=8080)`. It now cannot find the file I was looking for! I found an alternative for it to work -*virtual hosting*, but what I need is the method to check the file exists **when it is served**.

I've tried to type on the URL address bar the exact path, and it can find the file (*the browser downloaded it, in fact*): `localhost:8080/settings/config.xml`

Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks for helping.

### EDITED:

When I said everything is fine until I served it, I am referring on running my project **through this URL**: `localhost/project/public`

Comment: what is the local path of file?

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. It's on:   `wamp\www\project\public\settings\config.xml` @SafoorSafdar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add slash root to the path.

like this: `File::exists("/settings/config.xml")`